# MATLAB computing Bayesian Information Criterion with the fit.m results

Tags: matlab, bayesian

I'm trying to compute the Bayesian with results from fit.m
According to the Wikipedia, log-likelihood can be approximated (when noise is `~N(0,sigma^2))` as:

```
L = -(n/2)*log(2*pi*sigma^2) - (rss(2*sigma^2))
```

with n as the number of samples, k as the number of free parameters, and rss as residual sum of squares. And BIC is defined as:

```
-2*L + k*log(n)
```

But this is a bit different from the fitglm.m result even for simple polynomial models and the discrepancy seems to increase when higher order terms are used.

Because I want to fit Gaussian models and compute BICs of them, I cannot just use fitglm.m Or, is there any other way to write Gaussian model with the Wilkinson notation? I'm not familiar with the notation, so I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is your issue, but I think your definition of BIC may be misunderstood.

The Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) is an approximation to the *log of the evidence*, and is defined as:

[image]

where 
[image]
is the data,
[image]
is the number of adaptive parameters of your model,
[image]
is the data size, and *most importantly*,

  <sub>[image]</sub>

is the **maximimum a posteriori** estimate for your model / parameter set.

Compare for instance with the much simpler *Akaike Information Criterion* (AIK):

[image]

which relies on the usually simpler to obtain **maximum likelihood** estimate 

  <sub>[image]</sub>

of the model instead.

Your
[image]
is simply a parameter, which is subject to estimation. If the
[image]
you're using here is derived from the sample variance, for instance, then that simply corresponds to the

  <sub>[image]</sub>

estimate, and *not* the

  <sub>[image]</sub>

one.

So, your discrepancy may simply derive from the builtin function using the 'correct' estimate and you using the wrong one in your 'by-hand' calculations of the BIC.

Comment: Reference: Bishop, C. (2006) "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning". p217

Comment: thanks a lot Tasos! But I still have no idea how I should compute the Pr(D|theta(or sigma?)_MAP). Can it be approximated by the sum of squared residuals divided by the number of samples?

Comment: Say "*s*" is your sigma, and "*D*" is your data. *theta* is the set of all parameters of your model. if *s* is the *only* parameter in your model, then that's the only parameter you need to worry about optimising. The "max-a-posteriori" estimate for *s* is the one for which the "posterior probability" term is maximized. This is usually estimated using Bayes rule: posterior = likelihood * prior / evidence. Similarly, the "max-likelihood" estimate for *s* is the one that maximizes the "likelihood" term. MAP is considered better than ML because it is adjusted by the prior (i.e. prior assumptions)

Comment: sometimes the the solutions for these problems (i.e. the *s* value for which the posterior is maximised) have a straightforward analytical solution. For instance, for a linear model (i.e. all parameters are polynomial factors of order 1), the sum of squares is a quadratic function, which means you can calculate the optimal parameter set analytically by taking its derivative to be zero, and this solution will correspond to the ML solution. Typically, the MAP solution is the same optimisation problem but with an added "regulariser" quadratic term to the sum of squares.

Comment: Read chapter 1 of Bishop! It's all there, and explained really well! :D